# Getting 0 in database as result of query

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi all newbie here :) Don't know if this is correct title, so sorry if not...

I'm trying to input data from one table to another for right user

controller:

```
function Admin(){
    $user = $this->input->post('username'); //there is one text field in view page were you input username
    $this->user->getEmail($user);
    if($this->user->getUser($user)){
        $this->user->Input_Admin();
        $this->Success();
    }
    $this->Fail();
}
```

model:

```
function Input_Admin(){
    $k = array(
        'Name' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
    );  
    $a = $this->db->insert('admin', $k);

    return $a;
}

function getEmail($user){
    $this->db->select('Email');
    $this->db->where('username', $user);
    $q = $this->db->get('users');
    if($q->num_rows > 0){
        return $q->result();
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

There is 3 fields in admin table id, name, email... the function for name is working like a charm but for email always input 0.... so what i'm doing wrong?

As req here is view:

```
<form name="info" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user_controler/admin">
    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center" bgcolor="#FFCC99">
            <tr> 
                <td width="25%">Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" size="30"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="6"> 
                    <div align="center"> 
                        <input type="submit" name="Confirm" value="Confirm">
                        <input type="reset" name="Cancel" value="CANCEL">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Inputting username in table is working but for email it put only 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is `<input type="text" name="Email" size="30">` ?

you have not that in html, so you get 0 value

put that in html , so the post request will send email too to your controller ;)

just to make it clear:

```
$k = array(
        'Name' => $this->input->post('username'), //needs <input name="username"/> in html
        'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'), //needs <input name="Email"/> in html
    );
```

one more tip use this:

```
<?php echo site_url('user_controller/admin'); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user_controler/admin
```

more comfortable ,easy to read ;)

You can then try this if you want user email from db:

```
function Admin(){
    $user = $this->input->post('username'); //there is one text field in view page were you input username
    $results = $this->user->getEmail($user);
    if($this->user->getUser($user)){
        $this->user->Input_Admin($results);
        $this->Success();
    }
    $this->Fail();
}
function Input_Admin($data){
    $k = array(
        'Name' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'Email' => $data->email,
    );  
    $a = $this->db->insert('admin', $k);

    return $a;
}

function getEmail($user){
    $this->db->select('Email');
    $this->db->where('username', $user);
    $q = $this->db->get('users');
    if($q->num_rows > 0){
        return $q->row();
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to input email from form... when you input username of desired user the function should take the email from one table and put it to another together with username

Comment: yes, but here **$this->input->post('Email')** you are expecting a **$_POST['Email']** data,if is not there you get 0 :)

Comment: check i updated answer, not sure it will work at 100% i think you'll need to check if all ok but logic seems ok now

Comment: if i do it like that i get 2 errors :  A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$email

Filename: models/user.php

Line Number: 101

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'Email' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `admin` (`Name`, `Email`) VALUES ('seve', NULL)

Filename: C:\wamp\www\P-projekat\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330  Bur if i put only 'Email' => $data and in getEmail return true it put 1 in email column

Comment: dude you have to debug it by yourself, anyway do a var_dump($results); after $results = $this->user->getEmail($user); , you probably have to check db field names i don't know your dbschema :P